# Update statement using case and or

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
UPDATE Productions 
SET CountryCode = (CASE WHEN @SOffice='LA' OR @SOffice='GA' then 'USA' ELSE 'CAN' END)
```

Can anyone confirm if this is a correct update case statement. I seem to be running into an error of some sort. It seems correct to me.

I am working on an application and have this update statment:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Productions SET CountryCode = (CASE WHEN @SOffice IN ('LA', 'GA') then 'USA' ELSE 'CAN' END), ProvinceCode = '" + user.GetProvinceCode() + "' WHERE ID = " + newProductionID, conn);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

But when I build the application and run this functionality I get the following error:

> Exception Message: Must declare the scalar variable "@SOffice".
>   Exception Triggered by Method: OnError

What does this mean??

Comment: so what's the error, btw instead of using `OR`, you can write it this way, `@SOffice IN ('LA', 'GA')`

Comment: It's valid statement, it's working fine - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/876d9/5 So your error is related to something else.

Comment: Is SOffice a column? If so, remove the @ signs. Otherwise, the update doesn't really make sense. Whenever you pass a new parameter value in @SOffice, you update the entire table?

Comment: Since you are just performing an update, why aren't you using `cmd.ExecuteScalar()`?

Comment: @Brian Why would you use `ExecuteScalar` for an update?  `ExecuteNonQuery` is specifically for Inserts, Updates, and Deletes.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx

Comment: @Brian `ExecuteNonQuery` returns the amount of rows changed by the statement, which makes sense for updates, inserts and deletes

Comment: You are both correct... I get those two confused.  /blush

Comment: Well, according to the text of the error message, which says that you 'must declare the scalar variable "@SOffice"`, you're using the variable `@SOffice` bud didn't declare it first.

Answer (score 4):

```
declare @Productions table(
     ind int not null identity(1,1)primary key clustered
    ,CountryCode nchar(3) not null 
    ,SOFFICE NCHAR(2) NULL
    )

insert into @Productions (CountryCode, SOFFICE) VALUES ('ITA','LA')
insert into @Productions (CountryCode, SOFFICE) VALUES ('ITA','VE')
insert into @Productions (CountryCode, SOFFICE) VALUES ('ITA','LZ')
insert into @Productions (CountryCode, SOFFICE) VALUES ('FRA','GA')
insert into @Productions (CountryCode, SOFFICE) VALUES ('FRA','BF')
insert into @Productions (CountryCode, SOFFICE) VALUES ('ITA','VR')
insert into @Productions (CountryCode, SOFFICE) VALUES ('GER','LA')
insert into @Productions (CountryCode, SOFFICE) VALUES ('CAN','LA')


SELECT * FROM @Productions      

UPDATE P
   SET COUNTRYCODE = CASE P.SOFFICE WHEN 'LA' THEN 'USA' 
                                    WHEN 'GA' THEN 'USA'
                                    ELSE 'CAN'
                     END -- CASE
   FROM @PRODUCTIONS P


SELECT * FROM @Productions
```

---

copy and paste the code above on sql server 2008 and you see it works fine.

hope this helps
marcelo

Comment: PLEASE DON'T SHOUT HERE. We can all read pretty well (or we probably wouldn't be here). The Shift key is on your keyboard for a reason - using it makes text easier to read and understand. Please use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put that parameter into the SqlCommand object you are using to execute the command, the `@` symbol signifies a variable in Sql, if `@SOffice` isn't a variable you need to remove the `@`, if it is you need to add a SqlParameter to the command before executing it

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("SOffice",DbType.Char,2){Value = "LA"})
```

And you should also include the other options in as parameters not by building a sql statement dynamically, it is a lot safer to add the parameters through `Parameters` property of the command... You also need to be wrapping your command in a `using` statement, and conn should be wrapped in one too

```
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationMananger
                         .ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString)
    using(cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = 
        @"UPDATE Productios 
          SET CountryCode = (CASE 
                                WHEN @SOffice IN('LA','GA') 
                             THEN 'USA' ELSE 'CAN'
                            END),
              ProvinceCode = @ProvinceCode
          WHERE ID = @newProductionID";
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new[]{
            new SqlParameter("SOffice",DbType.Char,2)
                {
                    Value = "LA"
                },
            new SqlParameter("ProvinceCode",DbType.Int)
                {
                    Value = user.GetProvinceCode()
                },
            new SqlParameter("newProductionID",DbType.Int)
                {
                    Value = newProductionID
                }
        });
        if(!conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Open();
        var resultCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your query @SOffice var, which is not declared

Use the below link.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z72eefad%28v=vs.100%29.aspx